# Moderators: Please replace tag `killing` with `killing-text`

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

To prevent confusion, facilitate search, etc., would a moderator please replace (add synonym, then merge appropriately) the tag `killing` with the better name `killing-text`?

"Killing" in Emacs can also refer to killing a buffer or killing a process, and it might even be (incorrectly) used for deleting a window, frame, etc.

For instance, this question, about killing processes, used tag `killing` (I removed it):
[Elpy: how to stop the underlying "py.exe" process?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/57759/105)

The tag needed is `killing-text`, for killing text.  If there is ever a need for other "killing" tags they can be added later.

Answer (score 1):

Done.  I've chosen `kill-text` instead of `killing-text` for consistency because we had a couple of other tags that started as `kill-XXXXX`.

Comment: Good. Thanks, Dan.